# Python formatted output as float of empty string

Tags: python

```
aa = ''

out_str = '%6.0f' % aa

print out_str
```

Is there a way to print an empty string with the formatting shown above? The reason why I need this is because the variable aa can sometimes store an actual float and other times it will be empty. But i do need to output it in the specified format. float(aa) does not work on an empty string.

EDIT:

How about the following?

```
aa = ''
ab = 23

out_str = '%6.0f%6.0f' % (aa,ab)

print out_str
```

EDIT:
In above example,
`aa = '', ab=23` would have to print six spaces, followed by 23 with four leading spaces

Comment: Fair warning: Don't ever edit the main part of your question, especially if someone provided an answer for it. Edits should be done post-main body. Questions not in line with the original question should be done in another post. I rolled back your edit and added in your new query.

Comment: sorry, will take care.

Comment: Is it possible for one of `aa` or `ab` to be valid and the other to be invalid, printing only the valid one?

Comment: unfortunately not, i have to print both. for whichever variable is invalid i have to print empty string....

Comment: So, `aa = ''`, `ab=23` would have to print six spaces, followed by `23` with four leading spaces?

Comment: exactly that! also, this is a toy example, in actuality there are about 8 more variables.

Comment: also, using your latest comment to update question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aa = ''
ab = 23
out_str = ''.join(('%6.0f' % var if var!='' else ' '*6) for var in (aa, ab))
print out_str
```

Comment: thanks! can your solution work if there are other elements to print in that string?

Comment: It would be better to clean up your data structure so that it only contains numbers that you'd like to print, rather than having to deal with it during printing.

Comment: the idea is to print an empty string if input data is missing.

Comment: Maybe you could validate the input data before saving it, tossing out any improper (empty) inputs?

Comment: thanks! as per my comment above: unfortunately not, i have to print both. for whichever variable is invalid i have to print empty string